# Octave's rref (reduced row echelon form) equivalent in C++ API

Tags: c++, api, visual-studio-2008, matrix, octave

I have developed a code in C++ using Octave 3.6.1 compiled for Visual Studio 2008. My program works good. Now I have to use `rref` (reduced row echelon form) in my C++ code, but I cannot find any equivalent C++ implementation for `rref` command.

In the following link, the `rref` command is listed among the Octave's core commands:

http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/overview.html

but I cannot find any class or method equivalent to `rref` in the following Octave C++ API:

http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/annotated.html

I appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large majority of Octave functions are implemented in Octave itself and are not available as C++ methods. Indeed, if you try `which rref` (in Octave 3.8.2), you will get something like:

```
octave-cli-3.8.2> man rref 
'rref' is a function from the file /usr/local/share/octave/3.8.2/m/linear-algebra/rref.m
```

which shows the .m file where it is implemented. How to make use of such functions in C++ is explained in the [Octave manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter).  The exact documentation of interest depends whether you are writing an [oct function](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Calling-Octave-Functions-from-Oct_002dFiles.html), or a [standalone program](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html), which is not clear from your question.

Comment: I had another question, I just thought I'd ask. I'm using `EIG` class of Octave in my C++ code. Actually, it works good. The only minor issue which I have is that it determines algorithm automatically based on the argument list of `EIG` constructor. I was wondering if there is a way to determine algorithm for the `EIG` class. I noticed that there is an optional argument called `info`, I looked into C++ source code to see if it relates to algorithm but I couldn't figure it out.